# Can Autodesk Viewer be restricted to only users under a organization account?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm integrating Autodesk Viewer in an application, and it uses Model Derivative API to translate files, which is a paid service.
Can this integration be restricted to allow access only for users under a organization account? Meaning if a random autodesk account outside the organization tries to use the integration, it will not be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are using 3 legged authentication? As a simple way of filtering out users from outside your organization, once they have authenticated you can get their Autodesk account details https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/users-@me-GET/ which includes the email address assigned to their account, and decide from that if they should have access.